# How to call 2 different method inside a method

Tags: java, informatica, mdm

i have cleanse method which is cleaning data while i am giving input from eclipse console, while entering i have putted some field as null, i am storing the cleanse data in map and calling that data in 2 different method for searching but it is calling everytime one method only

```
public void cleanse(SiperianClient oSiperianClient) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Field accountfield = new Field();
    accountfield.setName("Acct_Name");
    writeStringLog("Enter Account Name:");
    accountfield.setValue(sc.nextLine()); // "Arthritis Group"
    record.setField(accountfield);
    /// ...so on ..
    Map<String, Object> cleanseMap = new HashMap<>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {

        Record rec = iterator.next();
        // Collection<Field> fields = rec.getFields();

        cleanseMap.put("CUST_NM", rec.getField("CUST_NM").getValue());
        cleanseMap.put("ADDR_LN1", rec.getField("ADDR_LN1").getValue());
        cleanseMap.put("ADDR_LN2", rec.getField("NPI_ID").getValue());

    }

    if (cleanseMap.get("NPI_ID").equals(NPI_ID)) {
        this.SearchMatch(cleanseMap, oSiperianClient);
    } else {
        this.searchQueryMatch(oSiperianClient);
    }
}
```

here NPI ID is null as i have not inserted any value from console

Comment: Well, you'd have to check whether `cleanseMap.get("NPI_ID")` returns null and handle that case accordingly (depending on what you need to do in that case).

Comment: thanks mark its calling different method as we need to check if entered string is empty or null
if(NPI_ID.toString().isEmpty()){
    this.SearchMatch(cleanseMap, oSiperianClient); 
   }
   else {
    this.searchQueryMatch(cleanseMap,oSiperianClient);   
   }